# Spring cloud Stream custom functional style app configured for topics based on the stream and application name as it working for starter apps

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-function

I have created SCDF custom stream apps for sftp source by referring to the starter app. This app is auto-creating a topic for output as - function_name + -out- + index

As I looked at the default app the Spring Cloud Data Flow names these topics based on the stream and application naming conventions. This is not happening for function-style custom apps.

Is there any way to configure the custom spring cloud app to get the topic created as it's creating for default starter apps without specifying explicit bindings as below ?
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.sftpcustom-out-0=output

This will help us to reduce the additional binder configurations required for apps and it can be taken care of by Spring Cloud data flow.

Answer (score 1):

For custom apps, the only way to configure the topic is via the custom binding property you have listed.

The reason this works for the OOTB default apps is because our [application generator](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-apps-plugin/blob/bae7f10a5f942252a63c8dd9dbaa0fde7ac8260a/spring-cloud-dataflow-apps-generator-plugin/src/main/resources/template/app.properties#L15) sets this property in the apps `application.properties`.

Take the HTTP source default app for example. When it built you can see the generated property [image: generated-property].